# isLoaded observer does not fire at right time

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I think I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

When my application loads it needs to retrieve all companies and when those arrive it needs to set a property `activeCompany` on my `ApplicationController`. But when I bind an observer on `content.isLoaded` on my `CompaniesController` is fires before the data is loaded.

**Application**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    ApplicationController : Ember.Controller.extend({
        needs: ['companies'],
        activeCompany: null,
        activateCompany: function(company) {
            this.set('activeCompany',company);
        }
    })
});
```

**Router**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    enableLogging : true,
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('companies').set('content', App.Company.find());
    }
});
```

**CompaniesController**

```
App.CompaniesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    activateCompany: function() {
        console.log(this.get('content.length')); // 0
        console.log(this.get('content.isLoaded')); // true
        console.log(this.get('content.firstObject')); // undefined
        this.get('controllers.application').activateCompany(this.get('content.firstObject'));
    }.observes('content.isLoaded')
});
```

Why does `content.isLoaded` fire when my data is not loaded?

Maybe my concept is wrong but the rest of my application depends on the `activeCompany` to retrieve other data. I also have a 'company-switcher' which also sets the `activeCompany` property.

When I change my observer to `content.@each` it fires for all the items that are in the Array.

**EDIT**

I could work around it like this:

```
App.CompaniesController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application'],
    activateCompany: function() {
        if (this.get('content.length') > 0)
            this.get('controllers.application').activateCompany(this.get('content.firstObject'));
    }.observes('content.firstObject.isLoaded')
});
```

This only fires when my `firstObject` changes.

Comment: Try changing App.Company.find() to App.Store.findQuery(App.Company)

Comment: App.Store has no method `findQuery`, when I try it is throwing an error.

Comment: oh I assumed that you are not getting the isLoaded property at all & the previous comment dates back to the older version of ember, check the answer that I posted it might solve the issue

Comment: I'm using ember v1.0.0-pre.4-163-g693c818

Comment: This is strange ! isLoaded gets true when all the records are finished loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I should use `findQuery`. I tried it before like this: `App.Store.findQuery(App.Company)` but that didn't work. The right way of doing is like this:

```
this.controllerFor('companies').set('model', this.get('store').findQuery(App.Company));
```

I needed to get the store via `this.get('store')`